# Call to undefined function bi_to_str() after upgrading php from 5.2 to 5.5

Tags: php, upgrade

After upgrading php to 5.5, the following error occurs:

> `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function bi_to_str() in /var/www/index.php`

I know that it's not a coding error, but it could be a missing library. But could an empty value cause that error? Is there an easy way to load that library using  apt-get in Debian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't load the `bigint` library in your upgraded configuration.

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/big_int

Comment: I installed pecl big_int, but i get the same error, nothing has changed:              # php -info | grep big
PWD => /big_int-1.0.7
_SERVER["PWD"] => /big_int-1.0.7
_ENV["PWD"] => /big_int-1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Well with the help I received in the comments, I was able to come up with a solution.
It seems that it's just the function that is missing. I was able to create a file called big_int.php, fill it with the contents found [here](http://devops.stefaninicolombia.com/jcmontoyam/PortalCompras/blob/f0a5dbac3d96de3f8b6f8b35d919cbdd3714e825/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/__language__/52919c98/big_int.php), and just link to it using require_once in index.php, like this:

```
require_once('big_int.php');
```

All is well. Many thanks to  Barmar for the helpful tip.